# How to Add rules to IP Filter (Firewall in SCO)

Tags: ssh, firewall, sco, openserver

I need to add a rule (**allow any to any port 22**) to my firewall, so that I can `ssh` remotely into my machine.

I have had a look in the [SCO OSR600 Documentation](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/NET_tcp/ipf-howto.html#TOC_5) and I cannot find anything in there.

**Update**

I have managed to enable `ipfstat`:

```
#ipfstat enable
```

And now my firewall is active, I just need to add rules now.

But where do I find the rules text file?

Comment: I am currently looking for the ipf config file, but can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the rule, should be:

```
pass  in   quick proto tcp  from any  to any port = 22 keep state 
pass  out  quick proto tcp  from any  to any port = 22 keep state
```

in /etc/ipf.conf

Comment: Do you think I should try the same but for like port 80 and 81 as well? Or is that already included (default)? - I haven't tried adding the rules, just got into work now.

Comment: I just tried going in to the `/etc/ipf.conf` file, and it says it is a new file. I did this in both my user and root profile.

Comment: AWESOME, thank you, it has worked ... FINALLY!!!

Comment: I think that you, like me in the past, need a firewall editor. I suggest you to use fwbuilder http://www.fwbuilder.org/

Comment: But is that just a GUI or can I use a terminal to edit the firewall too?

Comment: Also, what does the `quick`, in adding the port, mean?

Comment: fwbuilder is a gui client for windows or linux. It helps you to generate the configuration for your firewall, then you can upload it to your server via sftp.

Answer (score 1):

Would think you add them the same as you would with iptables. Here is a quick doc on IPF though. http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/firewalls-ipf.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that site is for FreeBSD, and OK it might help a bit, but reading through that gave me a headache in the first place.